# Cron not running Error message

Tags: joomla, error, cron

Set up a scheduled task with my web host using the recommended:

```
/usr/bin/php5 /home/sites/mysite.com/public_html/en/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=USER&pass=PASS&key=APIKEY
```

Keep getting error message: Cron Not Running. No cron runs have been recorded.

Using Joomla 3.6.4

Comment: Please run the command you've pasted above when shelled into the host, and add the output to your question. Hard to tell you what's going wrong without any information about it :)

Comment: Just ran the command from the host as a test and this was the result: Your script returned the following: There was an error testing your cron job.

Comment: I also tried running a file called _test.php_ which I placed in exactly the same place as the cron.php file. The test.php file contained the following: `<?php

echo "Success";

?>`

When I ran this test when shelled into the host it returned the response: _Success_ so this seems to me to suggest that there is somehow a problem within CiviCRM?

Comment: In the following string: name=USER&pass=PASS&key=APIKEY

Comment: I have set the USER as the name of the person in the organisation who is going to be updating CiviCRM. This is her Joomla username. The PASS I've set as her Joomla login password and the APIKEY is the CiviCRM key
Is this correct?

Comment: Better make a separate account for CRON only. Remember to give the account superuser access.

Comment: Please describe the steps taken to obtain the error message _There was an error testing your cron job._ - this is not a civicrm error message I recognise. We need to see the actual output of that command, run from the CLI on the webserver.

Comment: OK I created a new Super Admin specifically of the Cron but still got an error message. Then saw there was an update so updated to CiviCRM 4.7.13 but now get the error:

Comment: `<div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <style type="text/css" media="screen"> @import url(/en/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/en/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css); </style> `

Comment: `<div class="messages status no-popup"> <i class="crm-i fa-exclamation-triangle crm-i-red"></i> <span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span> <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">CiviCRM 4.7.13 requires MySQL trigger privileges.</div> <p>`

Comment: `<a href="http://www.chsbelgium.org/en/administrator/" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a></p> </div> </div> <script language="JavaScript"> function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } } </script>`

Comment: I've uninstalled and then reinstalled CiviCRM. When I click on CiviCRM from the Components menu I now get a blank page